# Paradoxical flag within Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, offensive

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

So always I see this snippet above, I got myself thinking how wrong it is. And there is one simple reason, this:

**"answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."**

I mean, from a philosophical point of view, opinions are made of facts, references, or specific expertise. Just ask yourself, from where your opinions come from? From your family, from society? Does not matter, every fact is observed, and the observer is not excluded from the observation, so any fact, reference or specific expertise is by definition also a opinion.

So, should we not ban this flag?

Comment: Yes, observation is part of what forms opinions - but there's clearly a difference between subjectivity and objectivity. I think it's pretty clear what the flag means.

Comment: You are effectively arguing that "1+1 = 2" is merely an opinion.

Comment: But 1 + 1 = 2 it is a opinion. This opinions represents the idea the given to elements, their sum results in a positive  combination. Sometimes, for example, in nature, sums dont results in combination(oil and water, quantum physics).

Comment: @JohnAugustine you're entitled to the opinion that `1 + 1 != 2`, however misguided, but don't expect your bank to agree...

Comment: Hahaha your philosophical point is interesting, but I think it does not belong in a place for Engineers. You have to understand the context where you are writing this. People won't like you questioning the line that separates true from false, especially in programming and computing, where results can be objectively tested.

Comment: Also you are confusing "opinion" with "scope of science". Sciences are categorically self-contained, and the idea of a sum in natural numbers does not have to apply to quantum physics interactions or how water and oil combine. The sum operator is different in those contexts; that does not mean "1+1=2" is less true.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To understand this close reason, it might help you to substitute some of the words, and by doing so create a real-world analogy:

> primarily putrid greens
>
> Many good salads generate some degree of decay based on the breakdown of organic material, but lettuce in this salad will tend to be almost entirely putrid green sludge, rather than lettuce, kale, or tasty dressing.